# How to get an incoming call view similar to Whatsapp or Messenger?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, callkit

I am willing to display a full screen incoming view upon receiving a push notification similar to Messenger or Whatsapp such as this image

[image]

What SDK API should I look at? I would be using hybrid development such as Ionic or Cordova.

Comment: Did you found a solution using cordova?

Comment: I couldn't find one ...